# R: Aggregate Data Table

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

How can I do this in a fastest way, because I have many values in columns

```
columns <- levels(dt$AER)

dt[, (columns) := 0]

dt[AER=="AMS", AMS :=1]

dt[AER=="BLL", BLL :=1]

dt[AER=="BLQ", BLQ :=1]

dt[AER=="BRE", BRE :=1]
```

Comment: can you provide the result of `dput(dt)` ?

Comment: you may consider to change question title as it is not related to *aggregate* at all.

Comment: This question looks identical to me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881073/creating-dummy-variables-in-r-data-table/18881195 However, nowadays we have `dcast` for answers like eddi's.

Answer (score 3):

```
dt = data.table(AER = c("ZZZ", "AMS", "AMS", "BLL", "BLQ", "BLQ", 
"BRE"))

dt[, idx := .I]

# use dcast.data.table before 1.9.5
dcast(dt, idx + AER ~ AER, fill = 0, fun = function(x) 1)
#   idx AER AMS BLL BLQ BRE ZZZ
#1:   1 ZZZ   0   0   0   0   1
#2:   2 AMS   1   0   0   0   0
#3:   3 AMS   1   0   0   0   0
#4:   4 BLL   0   1   0   0   0
#5:   5 BLQ   0   0   1   0   0
#6:   6 BLQ   0   0   1   0   0
#7:   7 BRE   0   0   0   1   0
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is to use binary search

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(AER = c("AMS","BLL","BLQ","BRE"), AMS = 0, BLL = 0, BLQ = 0, BRE = 0)
setkey(dt,AER)
dt["AMS", AMS :=1]
dt["BLL", BLL :=1]
dt["BLQ", BLQ :=1]
dt["BRE", BRE :=1]
```

If you use 1.9.5 you don't even need to do that, it uses `auto.index` feature and after first filter `AER=="AMS"` it will build an index behind the scene and reuse it in each next filtering - even using `==` operator - all behind the scene. You can set `options("datatable.verbose"=TRUE)` to see when and how it works. So if you are on 1.9.5 just turn the `verbose=TRUE` and try your own code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
cols = unique(dt[,AER])
colsWith1 = c('AMS','BLL','BLQ','BRE')

dt[ , (cols) := lapply(cols, function(u) as.integer(AER %chin% intersect(colsWith1, u))), .SDcols = cols]
#   AER ZZZ AMS BLL BLQ BRE
#1: ZZZ   0   0   0   0   0
#2: AMS   0   1   0   0   0
#3: AMS   0   1   0   0   0
#4: BLL   0   0   1   0   0
#5: BLQ   0   0   0   1   0
#6: BLQ   0   0   0   1   0
#7: BRE   0   0   0   0   1
```

**Data:**

```
dt = data.table(
  AER = c("ZZZ", "AMS", "AMS", "BLL", "BLQ", "BLQ", "BRE"), 
  ZZZ = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
  AMS = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
  BLL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
  BLQ = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
  BRE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you wish to achieve seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901153/converting-r-factors-into-binary-matrix-values) post.
Adapting @Sven Hohenstein 's answer to you notation, it would become:

> cbind(dt, model.matrix( ~ 0 + AER, dt))